# Evaluate object property when it is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am using a JQuery autocomplete AJAX plugin as follows;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myfield").autocomplete({ 
        serviceUrl:'autocomplete.asp?soc=' + $("#soc").val()
    });
});
```

It is not working because (I assume) the serviceUrl property is evaluated once on page load, whereas I want it to change to reflect the current value of $("#soc").

Can I achieve this with some sort of closure or do I have to manually change the property on `$("#soc").change()`?

Comment: Is that the exact code you're using? because .val doesn't give any result - you would need .val() for it to give any result.

Comment: I am using `.val()`, forgot to copy into the question sorry.

Comment: What autocomplete library are you using? I don't see serviceURL in the jQueryUI library.

Comment: @Francis http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs it looks like once you create the autocomplete object the options are bound. So if `#soc` is changing then you will need to update the serviceUrl each time.

```
//create variable to store your autocomplete
var ac = $('#query').autocomplete(options);
//update it when #soc changes
$('#soc').change( function() {
  ac.setOptions({ serviceUrl: 'autocomplete.asp?soc=' + $("#soc").val() });
});
```